# Disable iOS messages in-app sounds/vibration

Tags: ios, audio, messages

When you are in the messages app (this also happens on Facebook app) and you recieve a new message a sound will play even if you're looking at the thread where the new message came in.
How do I disable it? It's very annoying and battery consuming for no good whatsoever.
Any help is appretiated.
Regards, Rodrigo.

Comment: It does not consume any battery. Sound/vibration use almost no battery at all. It is annoying though.

Comment: It must consume more than plain nothing.. but I guess you're right, those things are well engineered.

Comment: Compared to having the screen turned on, and the CPU turned on, it really is nothing. An iPod Shuffle has a TINY battery and can play music for 15 hours.

Answer (score 2):

In the Settings App -> Notifications -> Facebook you can turn "sounds" off.

This will also turn off vibrations.

It will not distinguish between whether the app is currently running or not, it'll just always be off. If you want that, then you will have to send an email to facebook requesting they change how their app works.

Comment: I don't mind having no sounds at all on facebook, since I don't leave it logged in all the time notifications won't come through anyway. I'll try it out, but that is not my question, I'm more concerned about the sounds in the Messages app which is really annoying when I start chatting with iMessage (thankfully, it doesn't happen that often). Thanks for your answer!